# How to make a variable non delimited file to be a delimited one

Tags: delimiter, text-parsing

Hello guys I want to convert my non delimited file into a delimited file
Example of the file is as follows.

```
Name.  CIF    Address line 1   State   Phn          Address line 2 Country        Billing               Address line 3
Alex.  44A.   Biston           NJ      25478163     4th,floor XY USA              55/2018               kenning
```

And so on all the data are in this format.
First three lines are metadata and then the data.
How can I make it delimited in proper format using logic.

Comment: Please provide additional information. Do you know the column widths or do you need to 'guess' them from the metadata row(s)? What language do you plan to use to code the file conversion? What have you tried already?

Comment: Column width is variable and need to guess it from metadata rows, Unix shell scripts was a way when I used to format this kind of file, I tried replacing all multiple spaces with comma, but that didn't worked as there were some missing data as well in the second and third row.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts in the problem:

- how to find the column widths
- how to split each line into fields and output a new line with delimiters

I could not propose an automated solution for the first one, because (not knowing anything about the metadata format), there is no clear way to find where one column ends and the next one begins. Some of the column headings contain multiple space-separated words and space is also used as a separator between the headings (and apparently one cannot use the rule "more than one space means the end of a heading name" because there's only one space between "Address line 2" and "Country" - and they're clearly separate columns. Clearly, finding the correct column widths requires understanding English and this is not something that you can write a program for.

For the second problem, things are much easier - once you have the column positions. If you figure the column positions manually (or programmatically, if you know something about the metadata that I don't - and you have a simple method for finding what's a column heading), then a program written in AWK can do this, for example:

```
cols="8,15,32,40,53,66,83,105"
awk_prog='BEGIN {
nt=split(cols,tabs,",")
delim=","
ORS=""
}
{ o=1 ;
  for (i in tabs) { t=tabs[i] ; f=substr($0,o,t-o); sub(" *$","",f) ; print f 
delim ; o=t } ;
  print substr($0, o) "\n"
}'
awk -v cols="$cols" "$awk_prog" input_file
```

NOTE that the above program does not deal correctly with the case when the separator character (e.g. ",") appears inside the data. If you decide to use this as-is, be sure to use a separator that is not present in the input data. It may be better to modify the code to escape any separator characters found in the input data (there are different ways to do this - depends on what you plan to feed the output file to).